# I need to change the multi lingual links to a drop-down box? How can I do this

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, multilingual, form-control

I need help. I'm trying to create a drop-down box with the text French and English as opposed to the two links that I have now in my view. I'm working in MVC and I need to have a drop-down box that should auto-submit based upon the user's language selection (not having the extra step of a submit button), but just post based upon selection. There's probably some way to do it with select tags and option tags and some javascript but I'm just not sure how. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

 namespace MultiLanguage.Controllers
{
public class LanguageController : Controller
{
    // GET: Language
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Change(String LanguageAbbrevation)
    {
        if(LanguageAbbrevation !=null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageAbbrevation);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(LanguageAbbrevation);
        }
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
        cookie.Value = LanguageAbbrevation;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

}

Here is my View

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<ul>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("English","Change","Language",new {LanguageAbbrevation = "en"}, null)</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("French", "Change", "Language", new { LanguageAbbrevation = "fr" }, null)</li>
<li>@DateTime.Now.ToString()</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: anyone now how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Controller

```
public ActionResult Change(string languageAbbrevation)
        {
            if (languageAbbrevation != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(languageAbbrevation);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(languageAbbrevation);

            }

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
            cookie.Value = languageAbbrevation;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            Response.Redirect("Index");
            return View("Index");
        }
```

2.In Global

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Language"];
            if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt");
            }
        }
```

3.In html

```html
                    <div class="dropdown pull-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            @Html.Label(Project.Resources.HomeTexts.Language)
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("English", "Change", new { languageAbbrevation = "en" }, null)</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Portugues", "Change", new { languageAbbrevation = "pt" }, null)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

4.create resource files
HomeTexts.en.resx
HomeTexts.resx -pt default

5.then use labels 
 @Html.Label(Project.Resources.HomeTexts.Login)